# performing chi squared test in SAS using PROC FREQ

Tags: sas

Our university is forcing us to perform the old school chi square test using PROC FREQ (I am aware of the options with proc univariate).

I have generated one theoretical exponential distribution with Beta=15 (and written down the values laboriously), and I've generated 10000 random variables which have an exponential distribution, with beta=15.

I try to first enter the frequencies of my random variables (in each interval) via the datalines command:

```
data expofaktiska;
    input number count;
    datalines;
    1 2910
    2 2040
    3 1400
    4 1020
    5 732
    6 531
    7 377
    8 305
    9 210
    10 144
    11 106
    12 66
    13 40
    14 45
    15 29
    16 16
    17 12
    18 8
    19 8
    20 3
    21 2
    22 0
    23 1
    24 2
    25 0
    26 2
;
run;
```

This seems to work.

I then try to compare these values to the theoretical values, using the chi square test in proc freq (the one we are supposed to use)

As follows:

```
proc freq data=expofaktiska;
weight count;
tables number / testp=(0.28347 0.20311 0.14554 0.10428 0.07472 0.05354 0.03837 0.02749 0.01969 0.01412 0.01011 0.00724 0.0052 0.00372 0.00266 0.00191 0.00137 0.00098 0.00070 0.00051 0.00036 0.00026 0.00018 0.00013 0.00010 0.00007) chisq;
run;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The number of TESTP values does not equal the number of levels. For the table of number,
       there are 24 levels and 26 TESTP values.
```

This may be because two intervals contain 0 obervations. I don't really see a way around this.

Also, I don't get the chi square test in the results viewer, nor the "tes probability", I only the frequency/cumulative frequency of the random variables.

What am I doing wrong? Do both theoretical/actual distributions need to have the same form (probability/frequencies?)

We are using SAS 9.4

Thanks in advance!

/Magnus

Comment: Well you would have got same results by x=floor(15*rand("Exponential")) then proc freq; table x;

Comment: TESTP=(values)| SAS-data-set
IF you use TESTP=SAS-data-set you would not have to laboriously write down the the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ZEROS options on the WEIGHT statement.

```
data expofaktiska;
    input number count;
    datalines;
    1 2910
    2 2040
    3 1400
    4 1020
    5 732
    6 531
    7 377
    8 305
    9 210
    10 144
    11 106
    12 66
    13 40
    14 45
    15 29
    16 16
    17 12
    18 8
    19 8
    20 3
    21 2
    22 0
    23 1
    24 2
    25 0
    26 2
;
run;
proc freq data=expofaktiska;
weight count / zeros;
tables number / testp=(0.28347 0.20311 0.14554 0.10428 0.07472 0.05354 0.03837 0.02749 0.01969 0.01412 0.01011 0.00724 0.0052 0.00372 0.00266 0.00191 0.00137 0.00098 0.00070 0.00051 0.00036 0.00026 0.00018 0.00013 0.00010 0.00007) chisq;
run;
```